# Python - For loop will not replace every dictionary key with it's matching value... Only cooperating for last key & value in dictionary

Tags: python, css, dictionary, for-loop

So I have some code to make a module and I need help utilizing a `for` loop with `.replace()` in it.
    The problem is that when I loop through `variables`, and use `.replace(k, v)`, my code will only replace the last key with it's matching last value in the dictionary. This leaves all the previous keys left in the output without being replaced with their matching value... I need every key to be replaced with every value, and it will only comply by doing the last key in the dict

```
variables = {'font1': 'Harlow Solid', 'grey': '#454545', 'font2': 'mistral'}

style_sheet ='''/* Pyle Sheets */
hashone{
    font: Italic 70px font1;
}
hashtwo{                       # scroll down to see 'for' loop in question
    font: bold 45px font2;     # scroll down to see 'for' loop in question
}
hashthree{
    font: Italic 25px Harlow Solid;
}
dotsample{
    text-align: center;
}
hashbodyid{
    background: grey;
}
'''
replace_num = len(variables.keys()) # <--for loop/.replace(k, v) function
for k, v in variables.items():      # <--for loop/.replace(k, v) function
    content = style_sheet.replace(k, v, replace_num) # <--- here it is...

looped_content = str(content)
id_content = looped_content.replace("hash", "#")
clss_idContent = id_content.replace("dot", ".")
#------------
print(clss_idContent) # view output
```

Comment: If the problem doesn’t have to do with saving to file, please just take it out of your code. Btw, the `content` is just getting overwritten after each iteration...

Comment: Figured I would leave it to give the whole file as reference but, in hindsight that's a better idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a logical mistake in your code. Let's analyze your code.

Suppose `style_sheet` equals to `aabbcc`, and `variables` equals to `{"a": 1, "b" : 2, "c": 3}`.

What will happen during loop?

First loop:  `content = "aabbcc".replace("a", 1, 3)`, so `content = "11bbcc"`.

Second loop: `content = "aabbcc".replace("b", 2, 3)`, so `content = "aa22cc"`.

Last loop:   `content = "aabbcc".replace("c", 3, 3)`, so `content = "aabb33"`.

So do you notice where is the key point?

You should update original string during every loop too!

You can change your code like the following:

```
content = style_sheet
for k, v in variables.items():
    content = content.replace(k, v, replace_num)  #update original string
```

Comment: You are a saint and a scholar my friend... thank you dearly

Answer (score 1):

You overwrite `content` again and again in the loop while the source string for the replacement (`style_sheet`) isn't changed.

Comment: so essentially, I just need to **break** it off at the end?

Comment: nope, that just got the first key to work... that was dumb, obviously it would only do one iteration...
I figured it out i believe i need to add an inequality that runs the loop if the variable **replace_num** is greater than zero and then add **-= 1** so the value goes down by one each iteration...
Will update...